# Upload Base64 image as post on facebook using GraphAPI

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, angular6, facebook-access-token, facebook-ads-api

I want to upload base64 image (jpg,png) on facebook using facebook developers graph API's in angular 6

'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos' this api end I am using with passing formdata.
I am referring https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-from-canvas/

```
socailpostCall(imageResult) {
  let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("access_token",{access_token});
  formData.append("source", imageResult);
  return this._http.post('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos',formData)
}
```

I expect imge should uploaded on facebook as a post, but actually It shows

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) This endpoint is deprecated since the required permission publish_actions is deprecated",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200,
      "fbtrace_id": "AckVrByZBvyDeuoac00SVXN"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that it is not possible anymore to post to a user profile. You can only use this to post to a Page - with a Page Token that includes the `publish_pages` permission.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Creating

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to the docs you can see that the following endpoint has been deprecated

> Apps that have used these endpoints in the last 90 days (before 30th
>   april) can continue using them with API versions 3.2 and lower until
>   July 30th, 2019.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/4-30-2019-endpoint-deprecations

Comment: Thanks @luschn, but I want to post the image on my personal profile, not on the page...,So is it possible?

Comment: i guess you posted this at the wrong answer - as you can read in my answer, posting to your personal profile ist not possible anymore.